# How to convert msword doc file and pdf file into html content

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word

In my site user can uploads msword and pdf files. i need to read word and pdf file and to display as an html content to user. How to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomment using OpenOffice as a headless daemon on your server. OpenOffice is incredibly good at converting documents and offers an inteface for communicating with other processes. Unfortunately only python and java is supported. So you have to add some kind of glue code, to make it play nice with PHP. Thats the way I use to convert .doc(x)/.ppt(x) documents to pdf in my own webapp and works really neat.

Here is a guide for using OpenOffice and Python (you won't really need to code lots of python, promised!)for such conversions http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=3451

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use some [tool](http://www.investintech.com/products/developer/) for such kind of conversions.